# not allowed to load local resource C3

Tags: c3.js

I am new to C3 and am facing few issues. I have downloaded the zip to my local system and have unzipped it.

I have written this in my index.html, however I am not able to load the charts,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load c3.css -->
<link href="C:/c3-0.4.10/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="C:/c3-0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
```

I am following "Getting Started" from http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html

I know, there is no direct file system access and hence I am getting the error, however I am not able find out what exactly has to be added in the src field.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using what's called an absolute path i.e `C:/c3-0.4.10/c3.min.js`.

There are two ways you can get this to work.

1. Specify the protocol you're using to get the file. Much like you use `http://` for the web resource you need to use `file://` for an absolute path to local resources. `file:///C:/c3-0.4.10/c3.min.js`
2. You can switch to a relative path which would be relative to the file you're using for the webpage. If you were to put the C3.js file in the same directory as the HTML file you'd need only do `src='c3.min.js'`

Comment: As a note; I'd recommend option 2 for portability purposes if you wish to ever run this outside of it's current environment.

Comment: http://localhost:11111/xxx/webui/public/c3.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:11111/xxx/webui/public/c3.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
index.html:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: c3 is not defined
http://localhost:11111/xxx/webui/public/c3.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ... I tried both, but no result... Any other pointer?

Comment: Please don't post error logs in comments. a `404` means that the page can't see them. Try `src='/c3.min.js'` to make sure it's relative. Other than that all I can say is make sure all necessary files are at the same level as the HTML file.